# Python properties as instance attributes

Tags: python, properties

I am trying to write a class with dynamic properties. Consider the following class with two read-only properties:

```
class Monster(object):
    def __init__(self,color,has_fur):
        self._color = color
        self._has_fur = has_fur

    @property
    def color(self): return self._color

    @property
    def has_fur(self): return self._has_fur
```

I want to generalize this so that `__init__` can take an arbitrary dictionary and create read-only properties from each item in the dictionary. I could do that like this:

```
class Monster2(object):
    def __init__(self,traits):
        self._traits = traits

        for key,value in traits.iteritems():
            setattr(self.__class__,key,property(lambda self,key=key: self._traits[key]))
```

However, this has a serious drawback: every time I create a new instance of `Monster`, I am actually modifying the `Monster` class. Instead of creating properties for my new `Monster` instance, I am effectively adding properties to **all** instances of `Monster`. To see this:

```
>>> hasattr(Monster2,"height")
False
>>> hasattr(Monster2,"has_claws")
False
>>> blue_monster = Monster2({"height":4.3,"color":"blue"})
>>> hasattr(Monster2,"height")
True
>>> hasattr(Monster2,"has_claws")
False
>>> red_monster = Monster2({"color":"red","has_claws":True})
>>> hasattr(Monster2,"height")
True
>>> hasattr(Monster2,"has_claws")
True
```

This of course makes sense, since I explicitly added the properties as class attributes with `setattr(self.__class__,key,property(lambda self,key=key: self._traits[key]))`. What I need here instead are properties that can be added to the instance. (i.e. "instance properties"). Unfortunately, according to everything I have read and tried, properties are always class attributes, not instance attributes. For example, this doesn't work:

```
class Monster3(object):
    def __init__(self,traits):
        self._traits = traits

        for key,value in traits.iteritems():
            self.__dict__[key] = property(lambda self,key=key: self._traits[key])

>>> green_monster = Monster3({"color":"green"})
>>> green_monster.color
<property object at 0x028FDAB0>
```

So my question is this: do "instance properties" exist? If not, what is the reason? I have been able to find lots about how properties are used in Python, but precious little about how they are implemented. If "instance properties" don't make sense, I would like to understand why.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're avoiding using subclasses?

Comment: Why would you even want to do this? If all of your getter functions are just identical functions that return a value from a dict, why even have them? The only reason to have getters in the first place is if you need to run some code to generate the values.

Comment: @abarnert: Properties are also commonly used to create read-only variables, notice the lack of setters. You're right though, this is a pretty trivial example, my real code does have more complex getters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there is no such thing as per-instance properties; like all descriptors, properties are *always* looked up on the class. See the [descriptor HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html) for exactly how that works.

You *can* implement dynamic attributes using a `__getattr__` hook instead, which can check for instance attributes dynamically:

```
class Monster(object):
    def __init__(self, traits):
        self._traits = traits

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name in self._traits:
            return self._traits[name]
        raise AttributeError(name)
```

These attributes are not really dynamic though; you could just set these directly on the instance:

```
class Monster(object):
    def __init__(self, traits):
        self.__dict__.update(traits)
```

Answer (score 3):

> So my question is this: do "instance properties" exist?

No.

> If not, what is the reason?

Because properties are implemented as [descriptors](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html). And the magic of descriptors is that they do different things when found in an object's type's dictionary than when found in the object's dictionary.

> I have been able to find lots about how properties are used in Python, but precious little about how they are implemented.

Read the Descriptor HowTo Guide linked above.

---

So, is there a way you could do this?

Well, yes, if you're willing to rethink the design a little.

For your case, all you want to do is use `_traits` in place of `__dict__`, and you're generating useless getter functions dynamically, so you could replace the whole thing with a couple of lines of code, as in Martijn Pieters's answer.

Or, if you want to redirect `.foo` to `._foo` iff `foo` is in a list (or, better, set) of `_traits`, that's just as easy:

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
    if name in self._traits:
        return getattr(self, '_' + name)
    raise AttributeError
```

But let's say you actually had some kind of use for getter functions—each attribute actually needs some code to generate the value, which you've wrapped up in a function, and stored in `_traits`. In that case:

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
    getter = self._traits.get(name)
    if getter:
        return getter()
    raise AttributeError
```

Answer (score 1):

> What I need here instead are properties that can be added to the instance.

A *property()* is a descriptor and those only work when stored in classes, not when stored in instances.

An easy way to achieve the effect of an instance property is do def __getattr__.  That will let you control the behavior for lookups.

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't need to make that properties read-only - you can just update object `__dict__` with kwargs

```
class Monster(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
```

than you can make instances of that class like that:

```
m0 = Monster(name='X')
m1 = Monster(name='godzilla', behaviour='godzilla behaviour')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing what you want could be to dynamically create monster classes. e.g.

```
def make_monster_class(traits):
    class DynamicMonster(object):
        pass

    for key, val in traits.items():
        setattr(DynamicMonster, key, property(lambda self, val=val: val))

    return DynamicMonster()

blue_monster = make_monster_class({"height": 4.3, "color": "blue"})
red_monster = make_monster_class({"color": "red", "has_claws": True})
for check in ("height", "color", "has_claws"):
    print "blue", check, getattr(blue_monster, check, "N/A")
    print "red ", check, getattr(red_monster, check, "N/A")
```

Output:

```
blue height 4.3
red  height N/A
blue color blue
red  color red
blue has_claws N/A
red  has_claws True
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't necessarily recommend this (the `__getattr__` solution is generally preferable) but you *could* write your class so that all instances made from it have their own class (well, a subclass of it). This is a quick hacky implementation of that idea:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __new__(Class):
        Class = type(Class.__name__, (Class,), {})
        Class.__new__ = object.__new__   # to prevent infinite recursion
        return Class()

m1 = MyClass()
m2 = MyClass()
assert type(m1) is not type(m2)
```

Now you can set properties on `type(self)` with aplomb since each instance has its own class object.

@Claudiu's answer is the same kind of thing, just implemented with a function instead of integrated into the instance-making machinery.